# Implementation of CRC-8. What does the init parameter do?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashcode, crc

I want to write a program for CRC different standards (bit processing) Stuck on the init parameter. When init = 0x00 it works correctly, not only for CRC-8 ... But as soon as you change init, the values do not give out correctly. What is the problem ? Init only needs to change the initial value of the register?

CRC-8 / init = 0x00, poly = 0x07 - works fine
CRC-8 CDMA / init = 0xFF, poly = 0x9b - aldeady no

CRC-8:

```
   int CRC8() {
    dynamic_bitset<> regix = MyCRC::GetRegixAsBits(0x00, 8); // init = 0x00
    dynamic_bitset<> mess = MyCRC::GetIntAsBitset(0x41, 8);  // mess = 0x41
    dynamic_bitset<> poly = MyCRC::GetPolyAsBitset(8, 0x07); // poly = 0x07

    cout << regix << endl; // 0000 0000 == 0x00
    cout << mess << endl;  // 0100 0001 0000 0000 == 0x41 + 8 нулей
    cout << poly << endl;  // 0000 0111 == 0x07

    while (mess.size() > 0) {
        if (regix[7] == 0) {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
        }
        else {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
            regix = regix ^ poly;
        }
        mess.pop_back();
    }

    cout << hex << regix.to_ulong() << endl; // 1100 0000 = 0xC0 | 0xC0 (crccalc.com) OK

    return regix.to_ulong();
}
```

CRC-8 CDMA:

```
int CRC8_CDMA() {
    dynamic_bitset<> regix = MyCRC::GetRegixAsBits(0xFF, 8); // init = 0xFF
    dynamic_bitset<> mess = MyCRC::GetIntAsBitset(0x41, 8);  // mess = 0x41
    dynamic_bitset<> poly = MyCRC::GetPolyAsBitset(8, 0x9b); // poly = 0x9b

    cout << regix << endl; // 1111 1111 == 0xFF
    cout << mess << endl;  // 0100 0001 0000 0000 == 0x41 + 8 нулей
    cout << poly << endl;  // 1001 1011 == 0x9b

    while (mess.size() > 0) {
        if (regix[7] == 0) {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
        }
        else {
            regix = regix << 1;
            regix[0] = mess[mess.size() - 1];
            regix = regix ^ poly;
        }
        mess.pop_back();
    }

    cout << hex << regix.to_ulong() << endl; // 1110 0010 = 0xE2 | 0x28 (crccalc.com) FALSE

    return regix.to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: It sets the intial value of the register, as you have already correctly surmised. It isn't exactly such a mystery that different values give different results. I am struggling to see any kind of an actual question here.

Comment: @EJP I added a refinement in the code comments. The values of my program do not match the online calculators ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of operations of wrong. The order of operations for a left shift CRC should be MSB (most significant bit) of CRC ^= MSB of message, and if result is 1, then CRC <<= 1, CRC ^= poly, else CRC <<= 1. Then the process is repeated with the next to MSB of the message, and so on.

It's also not shown what the ordering of bits is for Get...Bits... .

For the first case I get 0xC0, for the second case I get 0x28 .

The code can be simplified by xor'in 8 bits at at time:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

BYTE gencrc1(BYTE *bfr, size_t len)
{
size_t i;
BYTE crc = 0x00;
    while(len--){
        crc ^= *bfr++;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            if(crc & 0x80){
                crc <<= 1;
                crc ^= 0x07;
            } else {
                crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return(crc);
}

BYTE gencrc2(BYTE *bfr, size_t len)
{
size_t i;
BYTE crc = 0xff;
    while(len--){
        crc ^= *bfr++;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            if(crc & 0x80){
                crc <<= 1;
                crc ^= 0x9b;
            } else {
                crc <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return(crc);
}
```

gencrc2 example using "long hand division" method, crc poly = 0x19b = 110011011, message = 0x41, appended with 8 zero bits (for remainder) .

```
                     11011000
           ------------------
110011011  | 0100000100000000       0x41 with 8 zero bits 
             11111111               crc init value is 0xff
             --------
             101111100
             110011011
             ---------
              111001110
              110011011
              ---------
               010101010
               000000000
               ---------
                101010100
                110011011
                ---------
                 110011110
                 110011011
                 ---------
                  000001010
                  000000000
                  ---------
                   000010100
                   000000000
                   ---------
                    000101000
                    000000000
                    ---------
                     00101000       0x28 is remainder
```

Comment: Strange ... How is this interpreted by division into a column? If we divide by hand, we do not get this result in any way (as for me)

Comment: "Long-hand Calculation for a One-byte Message".

Comment: In the elementary manual (Ross N. Williams) , this was made easier. Although it may not be simpler, but more understandable to the student)